# Angular 2 Only define ViewChild if *ngIf evaluates true

Tags: angular, dynamic, components, loader, viewchild

How can I only define a view child if it exists in template.
I'm using a dynamic component loader like this ...

**viewContainer.directive.ts**

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[viewContainer]'
})
export class ViewContainer {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

**part of the component.ts**

```
@ViewChild(ViewContainer)
private viewContainer: ViewContainer;

private _postalMapComponent: any;

private set postalMapComponent(component: any) {
  if(!component) {
    return
  }

  let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);

  let viewContainerRef = this.viewContainer.viewContainerRef;
  viewContainerRef.clear();

  if(this._postalMapComponent)
    this._postalMapComponent.destroy();

  this._postalMapComponent = viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
}

private get postalMapComponent(): any {
  return this._postalMapComponent;
}
```

This works fine using

```
<ng-template viewContainer></ng-template>
```

inside the template html file.

If I use something like this in the template ...

```
<div *ngIf="something">
  <ng-template viewContainer></ng-template>
</div>
```

... and `something` evaluates `false` I run into an undefined error

`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.viewContainer ...`

How could I solve this? Is there a way to only set the ViewChild in the component if it exists in the template?

Comment: Can't you just do `if(!this.viewContainer) return;` ? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Where is #viewContainer you are referring to?

Comment: there is no #viewContainer I'm referring to ... I'm using a directive

Comment: I think your error is what you're asking for, that the `ViewContainerRef` becomes `null` when the condition in `*ngIf="..."` becomes `false`. Isn't this what you're asking for?

Comment: yes I need a way to put the `<ng-template viewContainer></ng-template>` inside a `*ngIf* ...